# Ubuntu theme not applying to all applications?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, virtualbox, themes, gtk

Themes (not only Arc) don't seem to work with Virtualbox.

[image]

Virtualbox seems to be the only application with this issue. Is there a way to fix this?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ apt-cache policy virtualbox-5.2
virtualbox-5.2:
  Installed: 5.2.18-124319~Ubuntu~xenial
  Candidate: 5.2.18-124319~Ubuntu~xenial
  Version table:
 *** 5.2.18-124319~Ubuntu~xenial 500
        500 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It's a `qt` application.

Comment: Oh... so how are some users able to theme it? https://4bds6hergc-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/freedos-tutorial-2-768x629.jpg